# Python Optimum way for hashing tokens

Tags: python, hash

For some application, I need to create a function to unique integer key for each string token in a huge group of tokens, so that this hash value will be an index within a hash list.

One of the problems is that within the typical hash function it can get negative values, so I made it to the power of two, and I get the remainder of dividing by the list size so that the index will be always within the list size.

The other most serious problem is that I can get multiple tokens with the same hash values. Is there a way to create a unique hash values for each token, like based on the ord() of the characters, combined with the length...etc in order to avoid having multiple tokens with the same hash values?

```
import urllib2,re

size=10**9 #size of hash list
hash_list=[None]*size


text = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/972/972.txt').read()
tokens=[v.lower() for v in re.split('\W+',text) if v]
for t in tokens:
    index=hash(t)**2 % size
    if hash_list[index]==None:
        hash_list[index]=t
    elif hash_list[index]<>None and hash_list[index]<>t:
        print hash_list[index],t
```

Comment: **ARGH!** Don't use `<>`!!! It's been deprecated (and removed in python3) since centuries ago. Use `!=`. Also, when you compare with `None` you can (and probably should) use `is` and `is not` since it's a singleton.

Comment: thanks for the tip :) any thoughts about the question?

Comment: by definition hashing produces duplicate hash keys - collisions are to be expected - you don't want to hash you want unique keys

Comment: @gkusner exactly, I need a function to create a unique key for each token

Comment: @hmghaly: You mean, unique integer key for each string token?

Comment: @georg yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @hmghaly: treat your words as base-26 (or 52) numbers and convert them to ints. You'll end with huge numbers though.

Comment: Also, if you're parsing natural languages, as your link implies, your word list will be not _that_ huge: there are [1,025,109.8 words in English](https://www.google.com/search?q=number+of+english+words) and even if your source uses them all, it still does fit in memory on an average computer.

Comment: @georg what I'm talking about is a 45 Million line text file, where each line has around 20 tokens. I cannot fit this in memory for sure.

Comment: and I like the idea of converting to integers but with such large integers I will not be able to fit the hash list in memory

Comment: @hmghaly: and what your app does with these tokens? Count, sort, convert?

Comment: @georg basically count

Comment: @hmghaly: you could sort the data using [external merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) and then count the sorted list, which is trivial and doesn't require memory.

Comment: @georg I tried similar approach and it is not very effective for the size of data I'm talking about, and there doesn't seem to be a clear python implementation for that.

Comment: The hash function worked nicely for me, I just want to eliminate or minimize collisions, that's my question

Comment: So the tokens _aren't_ English words, then? As others have suggested maybe hashing isn't the best approach here. Also, a big hash table using standard Python objects will take up much more RAM than the equivalent in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to use hashing, `abs(hash(t))` is better (and faster) than `hash(t)**2`: you're still folding negatives onto positives, but the result will always be an `int`, whereas squaring will often give you a `long`.

(Bear in mind that while Python will automatically promote the result of an `int` expression to a `long` if necessary, it won't automatically demote a small `long` to `int`).

Also, squaring makes the distribution less uniform and hence increases the chance of collisions. But you don't need to do either squaring or `abs()` to get rid of negatives: the `%` operator will do that, anyway. OTOH, if you make the table size a binary power, you can use `>>` instead of `%`, and bit shifting won't distort the distribution like modulus of an arbitrary number does.

The Python `hash()` is very good, but you might like to experiment with using another hashing function to randomize your tokens before applying `hash()`, eg one of the family of `sha()` functions or `md5()`, which can be found in hashlib.

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement it yourself; use a `set`.

```
import urllib2,re
text = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/972/972.txt').read()

unique_tokens = set(v.lower() for v in re.split('\W+',text) if v)
```

Comment: I'm talking about a HUGE number of tokens that I will not be able to fit in memory, I used this text only as an approximation.